# Is it possible to convert a Dashcode Webkit Web app to "normal" html + css

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, css, dashcode

I have a Dashcode app I built, a blog. Nothing fancy...
HTML + CSS + Javascript + getting data from an xml file...

The way i see it...
1. Javascript should be fully supported by any browser (with *some* differences).
2. I would need to modify HTML a little, although the parts i used in Dashcode seems to use *basic* HTML.
3. Dashcode seems to make heavy use of CSS, with fancy webkit specific flags that don't *seem* that hard to replace...

I want to be able to access the app from other browsers. How do i do that? What do i need to watch out for, has anyone tried this before.

PS. Some things seem to work, others like buttons seem to disappear or some code does not transfer properly.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond changing the browser-specific CSS, I don't think there's anything you'd have to change. I don't know the specifics of your webapp, but unless you want non-standards support (IE6/7 for your XML, in which case you'll need to add activeX object XMLHttpRequest support), the javascript and html should not need changing between browsers.

To access the app from other browsers, you'll need to deploy it if you haven't already, then find the root folder and copy that. If you don't have another editing application already, I'd suggest [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) as a free app, or [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) as a (rather pricey) paid alternative.

N.B.: I've not actually ported anything from Dashcode per se, but this is based off of about 3 minutes of testing things in it and some experience porting websites.